# Copy over contents in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy

The question itself is pretty vague, basically what I need to do is I have a bunch of data in this order.
<month> <product> <quantity> I have this
for every month. Every month it has multiple products, so the same product can and will appear (but not neccesarily) in january and february. [It's basically this, the months and everything is in Hungarian but don't mind that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPI2L.png)
I need to copy over the <quantity> cells in another format where I have all of the months top and the product names on the front.
[So basically like this (still in hungarian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRNVp.png)
I also have to check if the product is there in the given month, and if it doesn't just don't write anything.
What sort of formulas can I use, to do this, so I don't have to make it manually?

Comment: Just use a pivot table. No need to over complicate this with formulas. Pivot tables were created to do exactly this :) 

Add your IDs in the rows, Months in the columns, and Quantity (SUM) in values. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your result screenshot, I assumed that you do not really want to copy each quantity. You rather seem to be interested in getting a better overview of your data.

This following approach does "sum up" all quantities per product and month. Your source list is on the left, the result on the right.

[image]

The highlighted cells feature the following formula (sample for F3).

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$12,$B$3:$B$12,$E3,$A$3:$A$12,F$2)
```

**Params** in order of appearance:

- Column that contains the values that should be summed up, here "Quantity" (Source list)
- Column that contains the "Product ID" (Source list)
- Cell that contains the respective/current "Product ID" (Target list)
- Column that contains the "Month" (Source list)
- Cell that contains the respective/current "Month" (Target list)

**Note:**
If you really need to "copy" each value, then this approach does only work as desired, if a product does not exist in multiple lines per month.

Answer (score 0):

Using a SUMIFS like this will get the job done.  In this example, I put your  in Columns A, B, and C.  I summarized it by month in the range from F1:R3.

```
=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,G$1,$B:$B,$F2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1yWw.png)

You may also want to consider adding the year as well.  You could either add a separate column for the year and then add that as a third condition to the SUMIFS, or you could use a date instead of the month name.